# What's the model, controller, view in the following backbone.js example?

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, backbone.js

I got this code:

```
(function($){
  var ListView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: $('body'), // el attaches to existing element

events: Where DOM events are bound to View methods. Backbone doesn't have a separate controller to handle such bindings; it all happens in a View.

    events: {
      'click button#add': 'addItem'
    },
    initialize: function(){
      _.bindAll(this, 'render', 'addItem'); // every function that uses 'this' as the current object should be in here

      this.counter = 0; // total number of items added thus far
      this.render();
    },

render() now introduces a button to add a new list item.

    render: function(){
      $(this.el).append("<button id='add'>Add list item</button>");
      $(this.el).append("<ul></ul>");
    },

addItem(): Custom function called via click event above.

    addItem: function(){
      this.counter++;
      $('ul', this.el).append("<li>hello world"+this.counter+"</li>");
    }
  });

  var listView = new ListView();      
})(jQuery);
```

from [this](http://arturadib.com/hello-backbonejs/docs/2.html) tutorial.

I understand that Backbone.js introduces a MVC pattern to the front end.
But in the code above I can't see that.

Can anyone explain that to me?

Comment: dont use mvc, see criticisms of oop in web programming

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's just the view part code. See other .js files in the same tutorial. Better check out all the files from 1.js to 5.js
Better check it from first: [Hello Backbone](http://arturadib.com/hello-backbonejs/)

Answer (score 2):

There is technically no controller in backbone.js.  The main structures are Models, Views, Collections (that act as arrays and contain lots of models), and Routers.

The link you listed -  http://arturadib.com/hello-backbonejs/ - is probably the best way to learn Backbone.js - especially with little background in Javascript.  So you are on the right track.  That project is a direct lead-in to the backbone.js ToDo list tutorial:  http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/docs/todos.html

This site will also explain things at a more basic level - I found it very helpful:  http://backbonetutorials.com/

Answer (score 1):

Note that Backbone View isn't the one you expected in MVC its more like a controller or the presenter in MVP. Here is a nice [article](http://blog.nodejitsu.com/scaling-isomorphic-javascript-code) that describes this differences.